# Firefox image position (overlay)

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I've been looking at this small issue for a while and I can't seem to fix it. It's an firefox only bug it's fine in IE Chrome etc.

This website I made for a client shows the issue. On the start of the page you see 2 wheel PNG images Three of these images are there, you can switch the z-index by clicking the round circles on the bottom of the image.

As you see the Black colour is slightly more down, I can't seem to wrap my head around the issue since the line height is 0 and the way the black image is positioned is the same as the grey one. They are slightly downsized due to a max-size: 100%, but resizing them to the proper (1000px) doens't seem to help either, (did this locally).

If you open the pictures in photoshop or w/e they're exactly aligned.

Anyone have any idea why it goes wrong on Firefox only?

--> example
Removed the example since it's a website.

Comment: Please include your code and a JSFiddle or similar sandbox link rather than just linking to your site.

Comment: sure is weird, might have something to do with the fact that they are relatively positioned instead of absolute

Comment: I'll add that later, not as easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird issue indeed. The only thing way I could get it to go away was to absolutely position the wheels. this would require you to set a height on `#infographic` and take off the `margin-top:-100%;`. Depending on how you use the `#infographic` container this solution might not be ideal for you, but at least something to consider to help solve your issue.

Comment: I resolved it in this way. I still have 1 relative and two absolute. (So the first 2 absolute third relative).

It's silly that this didn't work with the -margin allthough it is a bit hackish.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the whitespace between the elements. Unfortunately, some browsers observe it and thus some space is shown although it shouldn't. You can use this workaround:
Generally work with `rem` instead of `em`, you need it for this workaround to work easier. First you have to set the `font-size` of `.infographic` to zero. Every element inside your `.infographic` will now become a `font-size` of zero because you're using `em`. That's the reason why you should now change to `rem`, at least for the elements inside `.infographic`.

Now you're done.

Comment: I attempted this without whitespace so I don't think this works but I'll try.